# How to get HTML tag included in the output using a helper method

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I want to use html tag in helper

```
def get_hotel_theme_names(hotel)
    themes = hotel.themes.map(&:theme_names).to_a
    themes = themes.blank? ? nil :  themes.join(", ")
    themes
end
```

I have `get_theme_name helper` method which return `themes of hotel`, But I want to use link on each theme

Like: get_hotel_theme_name returns `funny, entertainment, fun, music,`

So I want to theme_name like: `funny (X), entertainment (X), fun (X), music (X),`

Where `(X)` has `link` to `delete theme`, So how to add link on it

Comment: Going through a helper like this seems like a less than ideal way to get what you want. Why not just iterate over the `hotel.themes` in the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just concat any tags you want into the output.

```
def get_hotel_theme_names(hotel)
    output = []
    hotel.themes.each do |theme|
      output << (theme.theme_names + link_to('(X)', theme, :method=>:delete, :confirm=>'sure?'))          
      #or add other tags you want
      #output << '<div>test</div>'
    end

    output.join(',').html_safe
end
```